# PHP Output of a SQL Selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working SQL Selection (thanks prince ;) ).

I would like to output the config_values from this sql selection

I tried already this without success. Thank you

```
$statistik = "
SELECT config_value
FROM  `phpbb3_config` 
WHERE config_name IN ('num_posts', 'num_topics', 'num_users')
";
$statshow = mysql_query($statistik) or die("Service temporairly unavailable");
$rowstat = mysql_fetch_array($statshow); 
echo $rowstat['num_posts'];
echo $rowstat['num_topics'];
echo $rowstat['num_users'];
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get an error? Are you sure your query returns results?

Comment: You are only select the `config_value` field, you are not selecting a field called `num_posts` or `num_topics` or `num_users`.  Also note that `mysql_fetch_array` only returns one row at a time.

Comment: Where is your connection string? Please don't use `mysql_` functions.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as `echo $rowstat['config_value']`. You're not selecting the `num_posts`, `num_topics`, and `num_users` columns, so those echo statements will not output anything.

**Edit:** To output multiple rows, change `$rowstat = mysql_fetch_array($statshow);` to a loop that goes through each row in the result set, like so:

```
while ( $rowstat = mysql_fetch_array($statshow) ) {
    echo $rowstat['config_value'];
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I use the myphpadmin it get 3 config_values. The connection works. When I use echo $rowstat['config_value'] it get only the first value. I think I need 3 selections. correct? I thought its better to have only one...mmhh

Comment: Ah, you want to output multiple rows, I see. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is to also echo out the option name that goes with the value, like so:

```
$statistik = "
SELECT config_value, config_name
FROM  `phpbb3_config` 
WHERE config_name IN ('num_posts', 'num_topics', 'num_users')
";
$statshow = mysql_query($statistik) or die("Service temporairly unavailable");

while ($rowstat = mysql_fetch_assoc($statshow)) {
    echo($rowstat['config_name'] . " - " . $rowstat['config_value']);
}
```

And look into using the mysqli driver instead of the old mysql driver, which is slated to be removed from future versions of PHP.